# Value of global variable not showing when using puts

Tags: ruby, global-variables, puts

I have made a program that takes in an array of stock prices for each day, then returns the days on which the stock should be bought then sold. I have a global variable, `$negatives` showing the buy and sell day. I want to return this global variable as part of my puts statement. However, currently, nothing is showing up. I am not seeing my puts statement. Any idea what's going on?

```
def stock_prices array
        $largest_difference = 0
        array.each_with_index {|value, index|
            if index == array.size - 1
                exit
            end
            array.each {|i| 
                $difference = value -  i
                if ($difference <= $largest_difference) && (index < array.rindex(i))
                    $negatives = [index, array.rindex(i)]
                    $largest_difference = $difference
                end
            }   
        }
        puts "The stock should be bought and sold at #{$negatives}, respectively"
end

puts stock_prices([10,12,5,3,20,1,9,20])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your code. First, `exit` exits the entire program. What you are really looking for is `break`. In addition to that, you don't even need that check, so you should remove

```
if index == array.size - 1
    exit
end
```

As the loop will exit automatically.

Finally, if you want the function to return `$difference` you should put `$difference` on the final line of your function.

There are more issues with your code (seems like you have an extra loop, and you should use do...end for multi-line blocks), but going into them seems more appropriate for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I shouldn't need to return the `$difference` but I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for the tip about the Code-Review, I was going to do that once I solved this issue.

Comment: You were right in asking here, CR is for working code only. Get it working here, make it beautiful there!